# PHP Finding a minimum acceleration of an array

Tags: php, plot, line, minimum, acceleration

Let's say I have a plotted line, I use the x-coordinates of each point as index of the array and the y-coordinates as the values in the array. With this array, I need to figure out the line's minimum acceleration (the lowest point in the slope of the slope).

My initial idea was to begin finding the slope at every point by doing

```
slope[i] = (line[i] - line[i-1]) / (i - (i-1))
```

with

```
slope[0] = 0
```

and then doing

```
acceleration[i] = (slope[i] - slope[i-1]) / (i - (i-1))
```

with

```
acceleration[0] = 0
```

and then just sorting `acceleration` to have the lowest value first. But I'm not too sure if this will work.

Comment: Why not just use a language like R, MatLab, or even a TI-8x calculator?

Comment: This is needed for a project that's being done in PHP, it would be too much work for me and my team to incorporate a new language for our application just for this. And i'm not sure if my idea is the right way to do it.